# How to apply slide animation in android using titanium?

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I m trying to apply a slide animation from left to right using Titanium.
On window open I am running this code
**doctorDetailsWindow.animate({
            left:0,
            duration:300
        });**
This code is working fine on IOS devices but not on Android devices.
Is there any way if we can apply the same on android device too?

Comment: This won't work on Android. Here is the documentation where you can learn how to animate Windows: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window (Heavyweight Window Transitions in Android)

Comment: Thanks. I got my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Only for android you can try:

```
var screen = Alloy.createController("screenName", {}).getView();
screen.open({
        activityEnterAnimation : Ti.App.Android.R.anim.slide_in_right,
        activityExitAnimation : Ti.App.Android.R.anim.slide_out_left
});
```

In app -> platform -> android -> res -> anim you must create two new files called

slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="400" android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%" />
    <alpha android:duration="400" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

and

slide_out_left.hml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="400" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="400" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```